# Can't open and read a file using FreeDOS

Tags: batch-file, dos

I'm trying to get a simple FOR statement to open and read a text file using FreeDOS.

```
for /F %i in (fileName.txt) do echo %i
```

Evidently, FreeDOS doesn't support the '/'-options of typical DOS.

Just get: "Bad variable specification" when I try to use any '/'-option.

Question: I have a lengthy .txt file that contains MAC addresses that I need to update some EEPROM with. How can I read this MAC address file and then call the update .exe with the appropriate addresses?

BTW, I've NEVER used DOS and this shows it.

Comment: You need to ask a question, but you're correct in saying FreeDOS, like MS-DOS, doesn't support the /F (or any option) to the FOR command. Those options are extensions that only exist in Windows NT and successor versions of Windows.

Comment: You could go with [4DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4DOS) a replacement command line interpreter somehow mimicing the enhanced `for /F` syntax.

Comment: `TYPE C:\somewhere\fileName.txt`, `TYPE | MORE C:\somewhere\fileName.txt` or `FIND /V "" C:\somewhere\fileName.txt` may work for you.